# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a snippet of code which I copied from Firestore example:

```
Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return new StreamBuilder(
      stream: _getEventStream(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text('Loading...');
        return new ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.documents.map((document) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(document['name']),
              subtitle: new Text("Class"),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

But I get this error

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'
```

What goes wrong here?

Answer (score 421, accepted):

The problem here is that type inference fails in an unexpected way.  The solution is to provide a type argument to the `map` method.

```
snapshot.data.documents.map<Widget>((document) {
  return new ListTile(
    title: new Text(document['name']),
    subtitle: new Text("Class"),
  );
}).toList()
```

The more complicated answer is that while the type of `children` is `List<Widget>`, that information doesn't flow back towards the `map` invocation.  This might be because `map` is followed by `toList` and because there is no way to type annotate the return of a closure.

Comment: May be related to strong-mode or flutter using Dart 2.

Comment: This specific change is probably related to dynamic as bottom aka "fuzzy arrows" - previously it was okay to assign a List<dynamic> to a List<X>.  That covered up a lot of inference gaps.

Comment: TBH I haven't managed to reproduce his bug. Since his code is inferred as a `List<ListTile>` even without specifying it to `map`.

Comment: Well that solved the issue. But it is a bit strange, I am new to dart, so I cannot really tell I understood it.

Comment: I was facing the same issue (But my scenario was different). I think this is happening because of Dart 2 strong type. Once I changed the variable declaration to List<Widget> it started working.

Comment: Issue not resolved for me  -  My Code                                                                                 return genres.map ((category) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
        child: Chip(
          label: Text(category),
          labelStyle: textTheme.caption,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
        ),
      );
    }).toList();                    where  genres is declared as List<dynamic> genres

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Just to clarify even more `productData['first'].map().toList` here we get the type List<dynamic>. But we need List<Widget>. So doing this `productData['first'].map<Widget>().toList` . Now we will get List<Widget>

Comment: Could you explain why the `new` in `new ListTile` is necessary?

Comment: why Its not working for me any idea?

Answer (score 63):

I had a list of strings in firestore that I was trying to read in my app. I got the same error when I tried to cast it to List of String.

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'
```

This solution helped me. Check it out.

```dart
var array = document['array']; // array is now List<dynamic>
List<String> strings = List<String>.from(array);
```

Answer (score 37):

You can Cast dynamic List to List With specific Type:

```
List<'YourModel'>.from(_list.where((i) => i.flag == true));
```

Answer (score 32):

I have solve my problem by converting `Map` to `Widget`

```
children: snapshot.map<Widget>((data) => 
    _buildListItem(context, data)).toList(),
```

Comment: Thank you for such a simple answer!

Comment: why It's not working for me? dart null-safety

Answer (score 8):

My Solution is, you can cast `List<dynamic>` into `List<Widget>`, you can add a simple code after `snapshot.data.documents.map` into `snapshot.data.documents.map<Widget>`, like the code i will show you below

From this

```
return new ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.documents.map((document) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(document['name']),
              subtitle: new Text("Class"),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
```

Into this

```
return new ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.documents.map<Widget>((document) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(document['name']),
              subtitle: new Text("Class"),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
```

Answer (score 7):

I think that you use _buildBody in the **children** properties of some widget, so **children** expect a **List Widget** (array of Widget) and _buildBody returns a ***'List dynamic'***.

In a very simple way, you can use an variable to return it:

```
// you can build your List of Widget's like you need
List<Widget> widgets = [
  Text('Line 1'),
  Text('Line 2'),
  Text('Line 3'),
];

// you can use it like this
Column(
  children: widgets
)
```

Example (**flutter create test1** ; **cd test1** ; **edit lib/main.dart** ; **flutter run**):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Widget> widgets = [
    Text('Line 1'),
    Text('Line 2'),
    Text('Line 3'),
  ];

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("List of Widgets Example")),
        body: Column(
          children: widgets
        )
      )
    );
  }

}
```

Another example using a **Widget** (oneWidget) within a **List of Widgets**(arrayOfWidgets). I show how extents a widget (MyButton) to personalize a widget and reduce the size of code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Widget> arrayOfWidgets = [
    Text('My Buttons'),
    MyButton('Button 1'),
    MyButton('Button 2'),
    MyButton('Button 3'),
  ];

  Widget oneWidget(List<Widget> _lw) { return Column(children: _lw); }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Widget with a List of Widget's Example")),
        body: oneWidget(arrayOfWidgets)
      )
    );
  }

}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  MyButton(this.text);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Text(text),
      onPressed: (){print("Pressed button '$text'.");},
    );
  }
}
```

I made a **complete example** that I use [dynamic widgets](https://dartpad.dev/b37b08cc25e0ccdba680090e9ef4b3c1) to show and hide widgets on screen, you can see it running online on [dart fiddle](https://dartpad.dev/b37b08cc25e0ccdba680090e9ef4b3c1), too.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List item = [
    {"title": "Button One", "color": 50},
    {"title": "Button Two", "color": 100},
    {"title": "Button Three", "color": 200},
    {"title": "No show", "color": 0, "hide": '1'},
  ];

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Dynamic Widget - List<Widget>"),backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(child: buttonBar()),
            Text('Click the buttons to hide it'),
          ]
        )
      )
    );
  }

  Widget buttonBar() {
    return Column(
      children: item.where((e) => e['hide'] != '1').map<Widget>((document) {
        return new FlatButton(
          child: new Text(document['title']),
          color: Color.fromARGB(document['color'], 0, 100, 0),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              print("click on ${document['title']} lets hide it");
              final tile = item.firstWhere((e) => e['title'] == document['title']);
              tile['hide'] = '1';
            });
          },
        );
      }
    ).toList());
  }
}
```

Maybe it helps someone. If it was is useful to you, let me know clicking in up arrow, please. Thanks.

https://dartpad.dev/b37b08cc25e0ccdba680090e9ef4b3c1

Comment: This no longer seems to work. Can't assign e.g. ```Text('My Buttons')``` into the ```List<Widget>``` array. Getting ```The element type 'Text' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'```. What would be a workaround for this?

Comment: Text is a Widget and can be an element of List<Widget>. Check this pad
[https://dartpad.dev/6a908fe99f604474fd052731d59d059c](https://dartpad.dev/6a908fe99f604474fd052731d59d059c) and tell me if it works to you.

Comment: "The element type 'List<Widget>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'."   from your very first example. Doesn't seem to work anymore

Answer (score 4):

This works for me`List<'YourModel'>.from(_list.where((i) => i.flag == true));`

Answer (score 4):

Example:

```
List<dynamic> listOne = ['111','222']
List<String> ListTwo = listOne.cast<String>();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think , after changing the type of List from dynamic to String  & doing **hot reload** will give this error , **hot restart is the solution..**

Remember : hot restart only rebuild the build() function , not the whole class & declaring the List at the top of class is outside of build() function

Answer (score 1):

changing to the list by adding `.toList()` resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
List list = [];
```

to this:

```
List<Widget> list = [];
```

Solved My Problem!!