# Why toList() creates a List<dynamic> in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have this method, which compiles with no problems in Dart 2. However at run-time I get the following error

> type '`List<dynamic>`' is not a subtype of type '`List<ExchangeRate>`'

As you see in the code I create and return new ExchangeRate objects within `.map()` and then after that I return a `rateEntries.toList()` which I expect to be of type `List<ExchangeRate>`, however it seems to be inferred as type `List<dynamic>`!!!

```
@override
Future<List<ExchangeRate>> getExchangeRatesAt(DateTime time, Currency baseCurrency) async {
  final http.Client client = http.Client();
  final String uri = "some uri ...";
  return await client
    .get(uri)
    .then((response) {
      var jsonEntries = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      var rateJsonEntries = jsonEntries["rates"].entries.toList();
      var rateEntries = rateJsonEntries.map((x) {
        return new ExchangeRate(x.value.toDouble());
      });
      return rateEntries.toList(); // WHY IS IT RETURNING A List<dynamic> here?
    })
    .catchError((e) => print(e))
    .whenComplete(() => client.close());
}
```

However if I cast it specifically to ExchangeRate it would be fine.

```
    return rateEntries.toList().cast<ExchangeRate>();
```

This casting at the end seems redundant to me, why should I need it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, it seems that the cast is necessary to fully define the type.

But, you can avoid the cast if you add any of the following snippets:

1. Give the correct type to the `rateJsonEntries` variable

   `List<dynamic> rateJsonEntries = jsonEntries["rates"].entries.toList();`

   For whatever reason this works in my case.
2. Add the parameter type to the `map()` method

   `var rateEntries = rateJsonEntries.map<ExchangeRate>((x) {
        return new ExchangeRate(x.value.toDouble());
      });`

Comment: thanks. Your both workarounds works as there is no need to add `.cast<ExchangeRate>()`. I like your second workaround more. However, I don't understand why Dart needs specifying type for `.map` (i.e. `.map<ExchangeRate>()`) to be able to output correct type instead of `dynamic`.

Comment: The thing is that it may be due to a type inference problem. It has no sense that just by adding `List<dynamic>` in the first case everything works. If you just use `var` there and do a `print(rateJsonEntries.runtimeType)` it prints exactly `List<dynamic>`. As Jonah says in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603021 it seems that type inference fails in an unexpected way.

Comment: Thanks for the link that explains what might happen under the hood. So I accept your second solution as an answer to this question.