# Flutter error when trying to use ExpansionPanelList/ExpansionPanel with (Firebase) stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, widget

I have the following code snippet:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Accounts.getAccounts(widget.firebaseUser.uid),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        return ExpansionPanelList(
          children: snapshot.data.documents
              .map((account) => new ExpansionPanel(
                  headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text("Some title"),
                    );
                  },
                  body: ListTile(
                    title: Text("Some text"),
                  )
              )).toList(),
          );
        }  
      );
    }
```

This gives the error:
`type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<ExpansionPanel>'`

I saw a solution for it here: [type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603021/type-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listwidget)

But when I do it and add `<Widget>` just after "map" I get a different error:

`type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<ExpansionPanel>'`

No idea how to resolve this...

Answer (score 1):

To convert a `List<dynamic>` to a list of a specific type, you can do:

```
List<ExpansionPanel>.from(...);
```

I'm not exactly sure what variable in your code is the `List<dynamic>`, but wrapping it in the above statement should convert it to the correct type (and will of course fail if not all items are `ExpansionPanel` instances).

Answer (score 0):

Turned out replacing `.map` with `.map<ExpansionPanel>` did the trick here.