# Class 'List<DocumentSnapshot>' has no instance method 'call' in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

My firestore database looks something like this
[image]

What I am trying to do is, I am making a Future list of all the documents with the same uid and then making a ListView using FutureBuilder.

The part giving me the error is,

```
body: FutureBuilder(
        future: listBuilder(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData == null){
            return Container();
          }
          return ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
            children: snapshot.data((data) => _buildListItem(context, data)).toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
```

```
Future listBuilder() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    final String uid = user.uid;
    List<DocumentSnapshot> list = [];
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('entries')
        .where("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) => data.documents.forEach((doc) => list.add(doc)));

    print("------------------------------------------------------------------");
    return list;
  }
```

```
Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
      child: InkWell(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Text(
                  snapshot.data['type'],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                  ),
                ),
                title: Text(snapshot.data['description'],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30,
                    )),
                subtitle: Text(snapshot.data['time'].toDate().toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                    )),
                trailing: Text(snapshot.data['value'].toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                    )),
              ), 
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is the error,

```
Class 'List<DocumentSnapshot>' has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: Instance(length:3) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: call(Closure: (dynamic) => Widget)
```

Thank you!

Comment: where do u get the error, in the method listBuilder?

Comment: In FutureBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `map` method.

Like this

```
     ...
children: snapshot.data.map((data)=>_buildListItem(context,data)).toList(),
     ...
```

Comment: I get the error, `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'` when I do this

Comment: I have added the `listBuilder()` function for more context

Comment: @parthshukla can you add `_buildListItem ` as well.
Also, try this
`children: <Widget>snapshot.data.map((data)=>_buildListItem(context,data)).toList(),
`

Comment: Try this for all values. 

          `Text(
                  "${snapshot.data['type']}",//for all values
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                  )`

Although everything thing looks right but just as a precaution it might happen some `_buildListItem ` is returning null for some value.

Comment: This similar question solved it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603021/type-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listwidget