# How to solve: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, listview, updates, display, networkimageview

I want to update image from listofTaskNotApprove class which it will pass the object of documentsnapshot into the EditTaskNotApprove. Before I update the image, I need to display specific of image where the user will be select specific info  from listofTaskNotApprove. The problem is how to display the current index of image into the new screen?

ListOfTaskNotAccepted class.

```
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fyp/screen/RecordOfficer/EditTaskNotApprove.dart';
import 'package:fyp/shared/Loading.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';


class ListOfTaskNotAccepted extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListOfTaskNotAcceptedState createState() => _ListOfTaskNotAcceptedState();
}
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getUser(BuildContext context) async* {
  final FirebaseUser rd = await auth.currentUser();
  yield* Firestore.instance.collection("Task").where('uid',isEqualTo: rd.uid).where("verified", isEqualTo: 'TidakSah').snapshots();
}
class _ListOfTaskNotAcceptedState extends State<ListOfTaskNotAccepted> {
  List<NetworkImage> _listOfImages = <NetworkImage>[];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Aduan Tidak Diterima"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        ),
      body: Container(
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: getUser(context),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData) {
              return Loading();
            } else{
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                   DocumentSnapshot da = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                    _listOfImages =[];
                    for(int i =0; i <da['url'].length; i++){
                      _listOfImages.add(NetworkImage(da['url'][i]));
                    }
                    return Card(
                        child:ListTile(
                          title: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text("Sumber Aduan: ", style: GoogleFonts.asap(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                      Text(da['sumberAduan'], style: GoogleFonts.asap(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text("Nombor Aduan: ", style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                      Text(da['noAduan'], style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text("Lokasi: ", style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                      Text(da['kawasan'] + " " + da['naJalan'], style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text("Kategori: ", style: GoogleFonts.arimo(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                                      Text(da['kategori'], style: GoogleFonts.arimo(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                      height: 200,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Colors.white
                                      ),
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                      child: Carousel(
                                        boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        images: _listOfImages,
                                        autoplay: false,
                                        indicatorBgPadding: 5.0,
                                        dotPosition: DotPosition.bottomCenter,
                                        animationCurve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                                        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          subtitle: Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                              Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Text("Catatan: ", style: GoogleFonts.arimo(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                                    Text(da['comments'], style: GoogleFonts.arimo(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                          onTap: () {Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditTask(da:da)));}
                        )
                    );
                  });
               }
          }),
       )
    );
  }
}
```

Here is  EditTask class which I need to display current index of image that selected by user.

```
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



class EditTask extends StatefulWidget {
 final DocumentSnapshot da;

  const EditTask({Key key, this.da}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditTaskState createState() => _EditTaskState(da);
}

class _EditTaskState extends State<EditTask> {
  DocumentSnapshot da;
  _EditTaskState(DocumentSnapshot da){
    this.da = da;
  }
 TextEditingController _noAduan;
 TextEditingController _sumberAduan;
 TextEditingController _kategori;
  DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.now();
 @override
 void initState(){
   super.initState();
   _noAduan = TextEditingController(text: widget.da.data['noAduan']);
   _sumberAduan =TextEditingController(text: widget.da.data['sumberAduan']);
   _kategori = TextEditingController(text: widget.da.data['kategori']);
   myDateTime = (da.data['date']).toDate();
  _listOfImages = NetworkImage(da.data['url']) as List<NetworkImage>; // this line show the error 

}

  List <String> sumber = <String> ['Sistem Aduan MBPJ', 'Sistem Aduan Waze', 'Sistem Aduan Utiliti'];
  List <String> kate = <String> ['Segera', 'Pembaikan Biasa'];
  String kategori;
  String sumberAduan;
  List <NetworkImage> _listOfImages = <NetworkImage>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Kemaskini Aduan"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        ),
    body: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Center(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              TextFormField(
                decoration:InputDecoration(
                    hintText: myDateTime.toString(),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                onChanged: (value){
                  setState(() {
                    myDateTime = value as DateTime;
                    print(myDateTime);
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              TextFormField(
                decoration:InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                controller: _noAduan,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              DropdownButtonFormField(
                hint:Text(widget.da.data['sumberAduan']),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.perm_contact_calendar),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                isExpanded: true,
                value: sumberAduan,
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    sumberAduan = newValue;
                    _sumberAduan.text = sumberAduan;
                  });
                },
                items: sumber.map((sum){
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: sum,
                    child: new Text(sum),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              DropdownButtonFormField(
                hint:Text(widget.da.data['kategori']),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.perm_contact_calendar),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                isExpanded: true,
                value: kategori,
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    kategori = newValue;
                    _kategori.text = kategori;
                  });
                },
                items: kate.map((ka){
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: ka,
                    child: new Text(ka),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                height: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white
                ),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Carousel(
                  boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                  autoplay: false,
                  //images: _listOfImages,
                  indicatorBgPadding: 5.0,
                  dotPosition: DotPosition.bottomCenter,
                  animationCurve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                  animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
      ),
    )
    );
  }
}
```

[the image that need to display for update image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoDxm.png)
This is how I want to display image in class EditTask when the user want to update information from ListOfTaskNotApprove

The error show that "**type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String'**"
Can someone help me? because I had tried many method to solve this problem but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603021/type-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listwidget)

Comment: I think it was not suitable with my question. btw thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say:

```
_listOfImages = NetworkImage(da.data['url']) as List<NetworkImage>; // this line show the error
```

Yes, you can't cast a `NetworkImage` to a `List<NetworkImage>`.  You probably meant:

```
_listOfImages = [ NetworkImage(da.data['url']) ] as List<NetworkImage>;
```

Comment: it still did'nt work for me. =(. still get the same error

Comment: You added the `[` and `]` around `NetworkImage(da.data['url'])` and you got the same error?  That's hard to believe, the error should definitely be different, even if that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I already put the [ ] around NetworkImage(da.data['url']) and if I put the  cast NetworkImage that you suggested, it show yellow line, it means "unnecessary cast". And I tried to remove it and get the same error. 

Comment: Oh, duh!  Change: `_listOfImages = NetworkImage(da.data['url']) as List<NetworkImage>;` to just `_listOfImages.add(NetworkImage(da.data['url']));`

Comment: I already use this one. and still get the same error. =(

Comment: Unfortunately, then, I don't think we'll be able to help you solve your problem without seeing the full code in question because it sounds like something else you haven't revealed might be interfering.

Comment: One last thing you can try: `_listOfImages = <NetworkImage>[NetworkImage(da.data['url'])];`

Comment: I tried this method but unfortunately it still get the same error. Is that because my url is data type of array ? Can I discuss with you in chat room? I am really need to solve this problem because it was urgently to solve in period.

Comment: If you want more help, you're going to need to share enough of your code for me to actually troubleshoot it.  Here's a demo of the `List<NetworkImage>` in DartPad: https://dartpad.dev/c667fe72a1d8af49cb597d6fadf10805

Answer (score 0):

The thing is your are getting a list of url's from Firebase storage which are *Strings* but you are adding this strings into a list of type *Network Image* which is wrong. As a list of string cannot be converted to a list of Network Image.

There are 2 ways to resolve this-

1. Change your list type to List and then wherever you show this image use
   list data as an argument for Network Image.

   ```
    List<String> urls=new List();
    //suppose list is not empty
    ....
    return NetworkImage(urls[i]);
    ....
   ```
2. While adding url's to your list add an Network Image object and directly  use the list item while showing images.

   ```
    List<NetworkImage> list=new List();
    list.add(NetworkImage('some url'));
    ....
    return list[i];
    ....
   ```

Comment: I tried using the second one ways but it show error "type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'"

Comment: Can you share the source code of same

Comment: "imageUrls.add(NetworkImage(da.data['url']));" this code. show the error. is that correct?