# Getting `_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>')` error

Tags: flutter, dart

> Getting an exception saying `_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>')` in `.toList()` below.

```
import 'package:eva_icons_flutter/eva_icons_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:student_community/app/constants/colors.dart';
import 'package:student_community/app/constants/dimensions.dart';
import 'package:student_community/core/viewmodels/video_view_model.dart';
import 'package:student_community/meta/widgets/loading_widget.dart';

class VideoView extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<VideoViewModel>(
        builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(
              resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
              backgroundColor: bgColor,
              body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: model.streamOfVideos(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return loadingWidget();
                  } else {
                    return listOfVideos(snapshot, context);
                  }
                },
              ),
            ));
  }

  Widget listOfVideos(dynamic querySnapshot, BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
      controller: scrollController,
      isAlwaysShown: false,
      child: ListView(
        children: querySnapshot.data.docs
            .map((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) =>
                blockOfVideo(context, documentSnapshot))
            .toList(),

      ),
    );
  }

  Widget blockOfVideo(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {}, //Proxy provider of detailed screen,
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              documentSnapshot.data()['thumbnail']))),
                ),
                Positioned(
                    top: 195,
                    left: 355,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(
                            documentSnapshot.data()['length'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: whiteColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: darkColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)),
                    ))
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage:
                      NetworkImage(documentSnapshot.data()['userimage']),
                ),
                hSizedBox2,
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        documentSnapshot.data()['title'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            color: whiteColor,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        documentSnapshot.data()['username'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            color: yellowColor,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      EvaIcons.moreVertical,
                      color: whiteColor,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {})
              ],
            ),
            Divider()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603021/type-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listwidget)

Comment: Thank you very much `raina77ow` it fixed my problem.

Comment: One thing I love very much about Stack overflow is we get response within 24 hours. And  I am new to Stack overflow. This is my 4th question here and I got a very good response from you all. Thank you very much Stack overflow and it's community.