# Flutter The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'

Tags: flutter, dart

this is the error I get and I don't know how to solve it

The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.

Thank you in advance for help in solving

**SOLUTION**:
blind me found solution in: [type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603021/type-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listwidget)

```
  StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
                stream: FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults,
                initialData: [],
                builder: (c, snapshot) => ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: snapshot.data!
                      .map(
                        (r) => ScanResultTile(
                          result: r,
                          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
                              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                            r.device.connect();
                            return DeviceScreen(device: r.device);
                          })),
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                ),),
```

Comment: can you please share full code for more details like what's return type "FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603021/type-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listwidget)

Answer (score 1):

Streambuilder returns a dynamic list so instead of returning ListView, return ListView.builder:

```
 StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
                stream: FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults,
                initialData: [],
                builder: (c, snapshot) => ListView(  <------- change this with ListView.builder
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: snapshot.data!
                      .map(
                        (r) => ScanResultTile(
                          result: r,
                          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
                              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                            r.device.connect();
                            return DeviceScreen(device: r.device);
                          })),
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                ),),
```