# Type Casting Problem While Using `List.map`

Tags: list, flutter, dart, functional-programming

I am trying to use the `List.map` function but I can't make it work.
Here I have a `data` variable of type `List<List<dynamic>>`  and when I am trying to
perform the below operation on the `data`, it throws exceptions.

```
rows: data.map((i) {
    DataRow(
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text(i[0].text)),
        DataCell(Text(i[1].text)),
        DataCell(Text(i[3].text)),
      ],
    );
  }
).toList(),
```

The above code throws the following exception:
[type `List<dynamic>` is not a subtype of type `List<DataRow>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603021/type-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listwidget)

I tried different solutions provided on the above StackOverflow link. i.e

```
rows: data.map<DataRow>((i) {
    DataRow(
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text(i[0].text)),
        DataCell(Text(i[1].text)),
        DataCell(Text(i[3].text)),
      ],
    );
  }
).toList(),
```

or:

```
rows: data.map((i) {
    DataRow(
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text(i[0].text)),
        DataCell(Text(i[1].text)),
        DataCell(Text(i[3].text)),
      ],
    );
  }
).toList() as List<DataRow>,
```

or:

```
rows: List<DataRow>.from(data.map((i) {
    DataRow(
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text(i[0].text)),
        DataCell(Text(i[1].text)),
        DataCell(Text(i[3].text)),
      ],
    );
  })
).toList(),
```

None seems to work, while applying the above methods, in some cases I get a different exception from the one I
mentioned at the start i.e in some cases I get this exception:
`type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'DataRow' in type cast`

It works if I am not using a `List.map`. i.e if I declare a `List<DataRow>` variable and then populate it
with a `for` loop. Then it works.

```
   rows: buildItems(data),
    );
  }

  List<DataRow> buildItems(data) {
    List<DataRow> rows = [];
    for (var i in data) {
      rows.add(DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell(Text(i[0].text)),
        DataCell(Text(i[1].text)),
        DataCell(Text(i[3].text)),
      ]));
    }
    return rows;
  }
```

The above code works, it's just that I can't make it work while using `List.map`.

Comment: Have you forgor **return** statement inside of map function?

Comment: LOL! I think so.
Probably I didn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `return` statement to your map like so

```dart
rows: data.map((i) {
    return DataRow(
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text(i[0].text)),
        DataCell(Text(i[1].text)),
        DataCell(Text(i[3].text)),
      ],
    );
  }
).toList(),
```