# Dart only can infer type from `map` sometimes

Tags: flutter, dart

The following code in my test Flutter app fails with `Expected a value of type 'List<DataColumn>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'`

```
var columns = data![0]
        .keys
        .map((keyName) => DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  keyName,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                ),
              ),
            ))
        .toList();

    var rows = data!
        .map((value) => DataRow(
              cells: <DataCell>[
                DataCell(Text("${value['name']}")),
                DataCell(Text("${value['age']}")),
                DataCell(Text("${value['role']}")),
              ],
            ))
        .toList();
```

If I explicitly pass the type to the first `map` with

```
.map<DataColumn>((keyName) => DataColumn(
```

it works fine.

So why does the first map needed the type passed, but the second does not. This feels similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603021/type-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listwidget) SO question. But the answer there get's the code to work, but does not explain why it only happens in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `type` either in variable or in map type. You have two option to do that.

**One**: define the type when you define variable like this:

```
List<DataColumn> columns = data![0]
    .keys
    .map((keyName) => DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: Text(
              keyName,
              style: const TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
        ))
    .toList();
```

**Two**: define the type in map:

```
var columns = data![0]
    .keys
    .map<DataColumn>((keyName) => DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: Text(
              keyName,
              style: const TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
        ))
    .toList();
```

Because the `map` doesn't know which kind of data it deals with so it considers it as `dynamic` and it will through you an exception when try to pass list of `dynamic` to list of `DataColumn`.

Comment: @Zach was it what you want?

Comment: I knew how to fix the issue, I wanted why the map can't infer the type in the first example

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the type of `data![0].keys` is different from `data!`.

Sometimes the type cannot be inferred, for example if you have a list of strings that use a map with a function that returns an integer:

```
var data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var mappedData = data.map((x) => x.length);
```

In this case, the type of the elements returned by the map function is inferred as dynamic.

It is a good practice to specify the type returned by map explicitly, to avoid potential type errors.